# ScatterViewItem manipulation event handlers not being called

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, surface

I am developing a WPF Surface touchscreen based application which makes use of `ScatterViewItem` controls.

When using touch input, all manipulations work well: rotation, scaling, translation.

Unfortunately, when I try to execute some code when the manipulations happen, for example the following code in the C# codebehind, nothing happens.

```
ManipulationDelta += myItemManipulationDelta;

private void myItemManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
        Application.Current.Shutdown(); //just to see if it's even happening
}
```

I have tried adding similar handlers to `ManipulationStarting` and `ManipulationStarted` with no success.

Update:
As the answer suggested, I have attempted the following, without success:

```
public partial class MyControl: ScatterViewItem
{
//constructor for custom control

    private void MainWindow_ManipulationDelta2(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
         Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    private void MainWindow_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        // normal handling of the event.
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        ManipulationDelta += MainWindow_ManipulationDelta2;
        ManipulationDelta += MainWindow_ManipulationDelta;
        // more stuff ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I had to actually register a `ContainerManipulationDelta` event inside my custom `ScatterViewItem` based control in order for the event to fire correctly. Now everything works as expected.